# How should I start with tracking file changes/versions?

Tags: version-control, file-management

I've been working with a lot of my files on the go recently, and in the process often times  accumulated several copies of files in different stages of completion/revision. I'm working on any number of projects at a given time, so it's not always easy to remember or figure out quickly which version I should continue working on.

What type of options would you recommend that allow me to track changes locally and if possible with files I work on while at a remote location? I've never worked with file versioning or tracking systems, so not sure what direction I should be looking in. I work mostly with HTML, CSS, and PHP.

Any help is awesomely appreciated! Thanks.

PS. Don't know if I should have this in a separate question but what options are available for the same type of thing, change tracking/logging for files on server? Preferably something that not only vaguely notes a file has been changed, but that tracks specific changes that have occurred in files.

Comment: You'll get a lot of different answer, but personally I use `git` - it is very easy to set up and use, it's fast, and it does everything you need.

Comment: Any distributed version control system should be fine.  Git and Mercurial seem to be the most popular right now; bzr and Darcs might also be worth a look.  Subversion is not distributed, but if you want to have once central repository and various check-outs in various places, that might make some things easier to keep track of; on the other hand, any DVCS should be able to support this scenario as well, just not as its sole model of operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to me that github is prefect choice for your requirement. You can create repository for maintain the history, it's easy to use and **it is free**

https://github.com/